# iOS how to load images in the cells of table view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

my app contains of a root navigation controller which is linked to a table view controller with custom cells. I could make it work to load values from a plist into the labels but it does not work for the images. Thanks for suggestions.

```
cell.chapterImage.image = [[ContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"ic_menu"];

cell.Chapter.text = [[ContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

plist:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>nat_num</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Sample String</string>
    <key>ic_menu</key>
    <string>main1@2x.png</string>
</dict>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Loading images into a table view cell is no different from loading images anywhere else.

```
cell.chapterImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:
    [[ContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"ic_menu"]];
```

What you were trying to do is put a string value into an image.  This was working for `cell.Chapter.text`, because `cell.Chapter.text` expects a string to be assigned to it.  Meanwhile, `cell.chapterImage.image` expects an image to be assigned to it, so we must use `[UIImage imageNamed:]` which is the factory method for `UIImage` which returns an image object associated with the file name you specify with the string argument.

Comment: I used your code and still don't see any images. what else could be wrong?

Comment: Have you included these images in your project in XCode?

Comment: Try replace <string>main1@2x.png</string> with <string>main1.png</string> remove @2x from the plist image name.

Comment: @Greg The `@2x` will only make a difference if he doesn't have an image called `main1@2x.png` in his project.  And if he doesn't have `main1@2x.png` in his project, I can't imagine he has `main1.png` in his project.

Comment: yes the images are in the project. replacing the image name does not do anything. all i see is the background-color of the uiimageview which i can set in the storyboard.

Comment: an NSLog of the array looks fine: `{
        "ic_menu" = "main1@2x.png";
        name = "Sample String";
        "nat_num" = 1;
    },`

Comment: How did you add them to the project?

Comment: they are in a subfolder of the "images" folder. I can access them in another view of my app without problems

Answer (score 1):

You can get the image with this code:

```
cell.chapterImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[ContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"ic_menu"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are adding the image view to the cell's ciew as well? Just to be sure, please check that some form of the following snippet is there in your code:

```
cell.chapterImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[ContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"ic_menu"]];
[cell addSubview:cell.chapterImage];
```

Additionally, try resizing and positioning of the image inside the table view delegate [willDisplayCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3awillDisplayCell%3aforRowAtIndexPath%3a):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(LWLibraryListCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.chapterImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
}
```

Comment: i didnt not use the addSubview code before, but the result is the same. I will try the other option you mentioned later, thanks